# Fabric.js / fabricjs in Svelte, is there any workaround?

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs, svelte

I have tried this code in REPL but couldn't find any working example. I am trying to free drawing on canvas using fabric pencil brush, however, this is only a rectangle:

```
<script>

    const fabric = () => {
        fabric = new window.fabric();
    }
    
    function drawMD(){
        let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c')
        let rect =  new fabric.Rect({
            left:150, top, 150, fill: 'red, width: 200, height: 200, angle: 45
        })
        
        canvas.add(rect)
    }
</script>

<svelte:head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/500/fabric.min.js" on:load={fabric}></script>
</svelte:head>

<div className="MarkdownEditor">
    <canvas id="c" width="600" height="600" style="border:1px solid #000000;" on:click={drawMD}>
</canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the window part, there are some typos in the Rect object and `className` won't work in Svelte. If you want to directly draw without having to click on the canvas, you can do this inside `onMount`. Here's a working [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/fc2b2ffaad11427886a4e63dad77ecdc?version=3.46.4)
(when opening the REPL there might be an error`fabric is not defined` - just move the `<svelte:head>` one line down, then it's working...)

```
<svelte:head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/500/fabric.min.js"></script>
</svelte:head>

<script>
    import {onMount} from 'svelte'

    onMount(() => {
        let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c2')
        let rect =  new fabric.Rect({
            left:120, top: 10, fill: 'teal', width: 150, height: 150, angle: 45
        })        
        canvas.add(rect)
    })

    function drawMD(){
        let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c')
        let rect =  new fabric.Rect({
            left:120, top: 10, fill: 'red', width: 150, height: 150, angle: 45
        })        
        canvas.add(rect)
    }
</script>

<div class="MarkdownEditor">
    <canvas id="c" width="250" height="250" style="border:1px solid #000000;" on:click={drawMD}></canvas>
</div>

<canvas id="c2" width="250" height="250" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but a bug fix for the accepted answer, the following appears to fix the `fabric is not defined` error, where we wait on fabric to load before proceeding in `onMount`

```
<svelte:head>
    <script>
        window.loadFabric = new Promise((resolve) => {
            const script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src =
                'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/5.3.1/fabric.min.js';
            script.onload = () => {
                resolve(window.fabric);
            };
            document.head.appendChild(script);
        });
    </script>
</svelte:head>

<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    onMount(async () => {
        const fabric = await window.loadFabric;

        let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c2');
        let rect = new fabric.Rect({
            left: 120,
            top: 10,
            fill: 'teal',
            width: 150,
            height: 150,
            angle: 45,
        });
        canvas.add(rect);
    });

    async function drawMD() {
        const fabric = await window.loadFabric;

        let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
        let rect = new fabric.Rect({
            left: 120,
            top: 10,
            fill: 'red',
            width: 150,
            height: 150,
            angle: 45,
        });
        canvas.add(rect);
    }
</script>

<div class="MarkdownEditor">
    <canvas
        id="c"
        width="250"
        height="250"
        style="border:1px solid #000000;"
        on:click="{drawMD}"
    ></canvas>
</div>

<canvas
    id="c2"
    width="250"
    height="250"
    style="border:1px solid #000000;"
></canvas>
```